# 2D random walk within a bounded area

Tags: random, geometry, conditional, simulation

I want to simulate a random walk in two dimensions within a bounded area, such as a square or a circle. I am thinking of using an `If` statement to define a boundary. Is there a better way to define a bounded region?

Comment: Probably you do not need `If`. Is your stepSize always a unit in a random direction?

Comment: Yes the step size is unit in a random direction. At each point I use a random number to decide where to go. I want when I reach the boundary either go to other direction inside the boundary or simply abort the random walk.

Comment: [related Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/49063/125)?

Comment: @kguler My emphasis here is creating the bounded region.

Comment: I think now I can look at the codes provided and figure out how I can create the bounded region in a random walk. Later I will generalize this to create an arbitrary shaped bounded region. Such as a circle with a hole in it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To answer your question: I don't think it's a bad or good idea to use `If`. It depends on how you do it. To demonstrate I'll use `If` combined very powerfully with *Mathematica* 10's ability to tell if a point is inside a specified region or not.

```
step[position_, region_] := Module[{randomStep},
  randomStep = RandomChoice[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}}];
  If[
   Element[position + randomStep, region],
   position + randomStep,
   position
   ]
  ]

randomWalk[region_, n_] := NestList[
  step[#, region] &,
  {0, 0},
  n
  ]

visualizeWalk[region_, n_] := Graphics[{
   White, region,
   Black, Line[randomWalk[region, n]]
   }, Background -> Black]

visualizeWalk[Disk[{0, 0}, 30], 10000]
```

[image: Random walk in a disk]

This version of `visualizeWalk` accepts arbitrary regions:

```
visualizeWalk[graphics_, region_, n_] := Graphics[{
   White, graphics,
   Black, Line[randomWalk[region, n]]
   }, Background -> Black]

region = {
   Disk[{-25, 0}, 30, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}],
   Disk[{25, 0}, 30]
   };
visualizeWalk[region, RegionUnion[region], 10000]
```

[image: Random walk in a union of regions]

```
visualizeWalk[
 {Disk[{-17.5, 0}, 30], Darker@Gray, Disk[{-17.5, 0}, 15]},
 RegionDifference[Disk[{-17.5, 0}, 30], Disk[{-17.5, 0}, 15]]
 , 10000]
```

[image: Using region difference to create a region]

Comment: I hope your elegant solution will receive the attention it deserves.

Comment: Apparently `Element` is the fancy geometry function I was envisioning. Not intimidating to use at all (unlike most other geometry functions I've come across). +1.

Comment: I think the `position` should remain the same (instead of `position - randomStep`) when the next step is out of the circle, since there will be cases where plus step and minus step will both be out of the circle. Evaluate `visualizeWalk[region_, n_] := 
  Graphics[{Opacity[0.5, Red], region, Black, 
    Line[randomWalk[region, n]]}];
visualizeWalk[Disk[{0, 0}, 3], 1000]` for example.

Comment: @seismatica It's a very, very unlikely corner case in almost any region of decent size. I choose to write it this way because the OP specified this behavior in a comment, but thanks anyway.

Comment: It maybe that he/she wasn't aware of the corner cases, but you're right they are rare.

Comment: Your strategy of reversing the move when crossing the edge makes the step near the edge not uniformly distributed. Instead of 1:1:1:1 the move odds become 1:2:1 instead of the 1:1:1 they should be.

Comment: @Sparr This is what the OP specified. If I tell it to stay still instead of moving into a wall it will be 1:1:1:0 instead of 1:1:1:1, what would you suggest?

Comment: Anyway I changed it so that it stands still instead of moving into a wall now...

Comment: @Pickett. The first example, the circle one works, but because `RegionUnion`is not available in Mathematica 9 I cannot use the other examples. I really like your solution though, other solutions are great too. Would it be possible to keep the solution for Mathematica 10 and provide one solution for MMA 9? Is there an equivalent of `RegionUnion` in MMA 9?

Comment: @yashar I'm afraid not, but you can do something like if `Element[position,disk1] && Element[position,disk2]` instead of `RegionUnion` and `Element[position,disk1] && !Element[position,disk2]` for `RegionDifference`. I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: @Pickett 1:1:1 is my suggestion. that is, an even choice between the legal moves, not double chance of the move away from the wall.

Comment: @C.E. Hi, wonderful post, so glad I came across this! Thought you might be interested in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/197402/52181) as well, your input/ideas would be very valuable. Thanks anyhow for all your great answers here.

Answer (score 24):

I suggest using `Mod` - a natural thing for looped boundary conditions on a torus.

Finite torus surface area is your bounded region.

2D random walk generally is simple:

```
walk = Accumulate[RandomReal[{-.1, .1}, {100, 2}]];
Graphics[Line[walk], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Confinement to square region {{0,1},{0,1}} would be simple in principle with `Mod[walk,1]` (periodic boundary conditions) but visualizing will be hard:

```
Graphics[Line[Mod[walk, 1]], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

So I think logical, for periodic boundary conditions, to place it on a torus ( with arbitrary radiuses ):

```
map[φ_, θ_] = CoordinateTransformData["Toroidal" -> "Cartesian", 
              "Mapping", {r, θ, φ}] /. {\[FormalA] -> 1, r -> 2 Log[2]}
```

[image]

```
walk = Accumulate[RandomReal[{-.1, .1}, {10^4, 2}]];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], Line[map @@@ walk]}, SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Here's my implement of a random walk within a circle using `If` and `FoldList`. Please see @Pickett's answer for more thorough implementation for arbitrary regions. Code updated to flesh out behavior near edge of region (if a step becomes out of bound, the current position will randomly look for the other step types that would stay in the region). I also added some formatting to the display to indicate the positions and indices of the point and when it's about to hit the edge of the region (highlighted in red).

```
Clear[randomWalk]
randomWalk[steps_Integer, start_, region_] /; 
  start ∈ region := 
 DynamicModule[{stepTypes, stepList, alternativeStep, stepChoice, 
   positions, edgePositions, pointPrimitives, text},
  
  (* 4 types of steps: {{0,1},{1,0},{0,-1},{-1,0}}: up, down, left, 
  right *)
  stepTypes = Flatten[Permutations[#, {2}] & /@ {{0, 1}, {0, -1}}, 1];
  
  (* Generate list of random steps *)
  stepList = RandomChoice[stepTypes, steps];
  
  (* If a step were to result in position outside of circle, 
  the step is not taken, 
  an alternative step type is chosen randomly from the remaining \
types; also, 
  the position near the edge woule also be Sowed to be Reaped later. 
  Otherwise, the step is taken *)
  alternativeStep[currentPosition_, nextStep_] := 
   RandomChoice[
    Select[Complement[
      stepTypes, {nextStep}], (currentPosition + # ∈ 
        region &)]];
  stepChoice[currentPosition_, nextStep_, nearEdgePosition_] :=
   If[currentPosition + nextStep ∈ region,
    currentPosition + nextStep,
    (Sow[nearEdgePosition];
     (* else *)
     currentPosition + alternativeStep[currentPosition, nextStep])];
  
  (* List of all positions and near edge positions *)
  {positions, edgePositions} = 
   FoldList[stepChoice[#1, Sequence @@ #2] &, start, 
     MapIndexed[List, stepList]] // Reap;
  
  (* Display *)
  pointPrimitives[
    n_Integer] := {If[MemberQ[Flatten@edgePositions, n], Red, Black], 
    Point[positions[[n]]]};
  text[n_Integer] := 
   Text[Style[Row@{n, ": ", positions[[n]]}, 
     If[MemberQ[Flatten@edgePositions, n], Red, Black], Bold, 
     15], {Right, Top}, {1., 1.}];
  Manipulate[
   Graphics[{Gray, region, AbsolutePointSize[5], White, 
     Point[positions], pointPrimitives[i], text[i]}, Frame -> True, 
    ImagePadding -> 25], {i, 1, Length[positions], 1}]
  ]

randomWalk[1000, {4, 4}, Disk[{0, 0}, 7]]
```

---

You can export this as an animation by creating a list of frames e.g. by using `Table` instead of `Manipulate`. Don't forget to change `DynamicModule` to `Module` or you'll get an image of a table of frames instead of an animation using `Export["randomwalk.gif", frames]`. This is because even though it will look like a list of frames in the notebook, `DynamicModule` will still wrap that list. All credits to @Pickett for this tip. Warning: gif might be slow to load.

[image: random walk]

---

Code can be easily adapted to 3D

```
Clear[randomWalk3D]
randomWalk3D[steps_Integer, start_, region_] /; 
  start ∈ region := 
 DynamicModule[{stepTypes, stepList, alternativeStep, stepChoice, 
   positions, edgePositions, pointPrimitives, text},
  
  (* 6 types of steps for 3D *)
  stepTypes = 
   Flatten[Permutations[#, {3}] & /@ {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}, 1];
  
  (* Generate list of random steps *)
  stepList = RandomChoice[stepTypes, steps];
  
  (* If a step were to result in position outside of circle, 
  the step is not taken, 
  an alternative step type is chosen randomly from the remaining \
types; also, 
  the position near the edge woule also be Sowed to be Reaped later. 
  Otherwise, the step is taken *)
  alternativeStep[currentPosition_, nextStep_] := 
   RandomChoice[
    Select[Complement[
      stepTypes, {nextStep}], (currentPosition + # ∈ 
        region &)]];
  stepChoice[currentPosition_, nextStep_, nearEdgePosition_] :=
   If[currentPosition + nextStep ∈ region,
    currentPosition + nextStep,
    (Sow[nearEdgePosition];
     (* else *)
     currentPosition + alternativeStep[currentPosition, nextStep])];
  
  (* List of all positions and near edge positions *)
  {positions, edgePositions} = 
   FoldList[stepChoice[#1, Sequence @@ #2] &, start, 
     MapIndexed[List, stepList]] // Reap;
  
  (* Display *)
  pointPrimitives[
    n_Integer] := {If[MemberQ[Flatten@edgePositions, n], Red, Black], 
    Point[positions[[n]]]};
  text[n_Integer] := 
   Epilog -> 
    Inset[Style[Row@{n, ": ", positions[[n]]}, 
      If[MemberQ[Flatten@edgePositions, n], Red, Black], Bold, 
      15], {Right, Top}, {Right, Top}];
  
  Manipulate[
   Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5, Gray], region, AbsolutePointSize[5], 
     White, Point[positions], pointPrimitives[i]}, text[i], 
    ImagePadding -> 25, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", Gray}}], {i, 1, 
    Length[positions], 1}]
  ]

randomWalk3D[1000, {4, 4, 4}, Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 7]]
```

[image: randomWalk3d]

Comment: Sorry Pickett I updated my post just as you updated it! Will fix it now.

Comment: @Pickett, Thanks, I deleted my answer

Comment: Those are nice visualizations! (You already have my +1)

Answer (score 8):

I chose the `WienerProcess` as the underlying random process, as this will simulate a Brownian motion.

## Until Boundary Hit

```
Module[{rd = Transpose @ RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, 1000, .01}, 2]["States"], length},
 length = LengthWhile[rd, # ∈ Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {+2, +2}] &];
 ListPlot[rd[[;; length]], Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}, 
  Epilog -> {EdgeForm[Thick], White, Opacity[0], Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {+2, +2}]}, ImageSize -> Large]
 ]
```

[image: untilbountaryhit]

## Other Direction Inside the Boundary

First the single moves as definded by a `WienerProcess`:

```
randomMove = Transpose[Differences /@ 
               RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, 100, .1}, 2]["States"]];
```

These are

```
Length@randomMove
```

> ```
> 1000
> ```

steps.

We'll start at

```
start = {0., 0.};
```

and define the boundary as a square

```
box2D = Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {+2, +2}];
```

Now the random walk inside this box is created with:

```
last = start;
walk = First@Last@Reap@Do[
  new = last + randomMove[[i]];
  If[new ∈ box2D,
   last = new;
   Sow@new, Null],
  {i, Length@randomMove}
  ];
randomInTheBox = Prepend[walk, start];
```

In my last run these where

```
Length@randomInTheBox
```

> ```
> 882
> ```

points.

A plot of the result:

```
ListPlot[randomInTheBox, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Black, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  Epilog -> {EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], White, Opacity[0], 
             Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {+2, +2}]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: randomInTheBox]

The walk can be traced with

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[randomInTheBox, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, 
  MeshStyle -> Black, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[randomInTheBox[[p]]], 
             EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], Opacity[0], box2D}],
 {p, 1, Length@randomInTheBox, 1}]
```

---

If you need to run this simulation multiple times, it is beneficial to put these steps together, e.g.

```
randomInTheBox = Prepend[
  Block[{randomMove = Transpose[Differences /@ 
         RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, 100, .1}, 2]["States"]], 
         length, last, new},
    length = Length@randomMove;
    last = start;
    First@Last@Reap@Do[
      new = last + randomMove[[i]];
      If[new \[Element] box2D,
        last = new;
        Sow@new, Null],
      {i, Length@randomMove}]
  ],
  start];
```

---

The random process can easily be replaced by an other one and a different definition for the bounding area be chosen. Furthermore an extension of this approach to 3D is straight forward.

Comment: I'm not advanced enough to fully understand your method but it's very cool! Can definitely see the Brownian in there.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `RegionWithin` in *Mathematica* $11.1$

```
pol = Entity["Country", "Georgia"]["Polygon"] /. GeoPosition -> Identity;

Ω= Polygon[Map[Reverse, pol[[1]][[1]]]];
start = Reverse@CountryData["Georgia", "CenterCoordinates"];

points[pt_, r_, region_] :=
Block[{npt = RandomPoint[Sphere[pt, r]]},
While[! RegionWithin[region, Line[{pt, npt}]],
npt = RandomPoint[Sphere[pt, r]]]; npt]

path = NestList[points[#, 0.1, Ω] &, start, 1200];

Graphics[{{Ω}, {Blue, Thickness[0.0018], Line[path]}, {Red, PointSize[Medium], 
Point[Last[path]]},{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[start]}}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Walking infinitely in a random and acceptable direction within a rectangle on button click, 
stepSize = 1.

```
DynamicModule[{newDir, walk = {{0, 0}}, oldPos, newPos = {0, 0}, 
  acceptQ = -20 <= #[[1]] <= +20 && -10 <= #[[2]] <= +10 &},
 {
   Button["Next Step", oldPos = newPos; 
    newPos = {\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}; 
    While[Not@acceptQ@newPos, newDir = RandomReal@{-Pi, +Pi}; 
     newPos = oldPos + {Cos@newDir, Sin@newDir}];
    walk = Append[walk, newPos]],
   Dynamic@
    Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{-20, -10}, {20, 10}], Gray, Line@walk,
       Point@walk, Red, Point@newPos}, ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True]
   } // Column]
```

[image: randomWalk]