# How to construct new geometrical shapes in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, geometry

In my previous question [2D random walk within a bounded area](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57561), I asked how to implement a 2D random walk within a bounded area. In the provided solution, one can use `Rectangle[{-10, -10}, {10, 10}]` or `Disk[{x, y}, r]` to define the bounded region as a disk or rectangle. How can I define new bounded regions in *Mathematica*?

For example, how can I add these two `Rectangle[{-10, -10}, {10, 10}]` and `Rectangle[{10, 0}, {15, 5}]` to get a new region made of these two rectangles?

[image: new region]

Comment: What version of _Mathematica_ are you using? It's pretty easy on _v10_ I believe, would need to use `Polygon` on earlier versions.

Comment: `Element[position + randomStep, region]` is the line that determines if the new step is valid or not. If you use an earlier version than 10, you don't have access to `RegionUnion` so you can't combine arbitrary shapes. Instead you have to write `Element[position + randomStep, rectangel1] || Element[position+randomStep, rectangle2]` to indicate that both areas are valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Pickett's answer in the comment, if you are using  v10 then you may try this:

```
r = RegionUnion[Rectangle[{-10, -10}, {10, 10}], 
   Rectangle[{10, 0}, {15, 5}]];
RegionPlot[r, BoundaryStyle -> Black, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, this is in the docs and in Pickett's comment. I don't think the question can be answered until the OP specifies the version in use. If it's just about `RegionUnion` this question should be closed as "can easily be found in the documentation".

Comment: @Öskå yes, I agree.

Comment: Furthermore, Pickett's answer in the OP's first question uses `RegionUnion`..

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned Pickett's in the answer.

Comment: What would be the solution if I have access to MMA9. In the office I have MMA9 and at home I have MMA10. The reply answer my problem. However, What if I or others have access just to MMA9.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use `RegionUnion[]`, it is easy to produce a `Polygon[]` corresponding to the desired shape: this hinges on the use of the *undocumented* functions `` Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonUnion[] `` and `` Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine[] ``. (In much older versions, they were in the `` Graphics`Mesh`​ `` context.) In your case, you will need the additional step of needing to convert `Rectangle[]` into an explicit `Polygon[]`.

```
r1 = Rectangle[{-10, -10}, {10, 10}]; r2 = Rectangle[{10, 0}, {15, 5}];

new = Composition[Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine,
                  Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonUnion][{r1, r2} /. 
      Rectangle[pmin_, pmax_] :> Polygon[{#1, #2, #4, #3} & @@
                                         Tuples[Transpose[{pmin, pmax}]]]];

{Graphics[new], Graphics[Line @@ new]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: the composite polygon]