# Random walk using Module

Tags: scoping, simulation

I want to create a random walk using `Module`. The walk start at `{0, 0}`. At every step, `x` moves by a random integer in the range $[-a, a]$ and y by $[-b,b]$.

Comment: You just have to [search the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=random%20walk). In particular, see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html) under Aplications, and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/ConstructARandomWalkIn2DAnd3D.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [2D random walk within a bounded area](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57561/2d-random-walk-within-a-bounded-area)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `RandomVariate` with `DiscreteUniformDistribution`:

```
rW[a_, b_, n_] := Accumulate[Prepend[
  RandomVariate[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{{-a, a}, {-b, b}}], n]], {0,0}]

dt = rW[10, 20, 100];
Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point@#, Thick, Blue, Line@#} &@dt, 
 Frame -> True, Axes->True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

We get the same picture with:

```
ListPlot[{dt, dt}, Joined -> {False, True}, 
 BaseStyle -> {Thick, PointSize[Large]}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 3;
b = 5; 
randomWalk = NestList[# + {RandomInteger[{-a, a}], RandomInteger[{-b, b}]} &, {0, 0}, 100]
```

(*
`{{0, 0}, {2, 2}, {1, -3}, {-2, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}, {4, 0}, {4,
   0}, {3, -4}, {4, -1}, {2, -5}, {0, 0}, {0, 
  0}, {2, -3}, {3, -6}, {2, -11}, {4, -10}, {4, -5}, {7, -3}, {9, \
-3}, {6, -8}, {9, -12}, {7, -16}, {5, -11}, {6, -16}, {4, -11}, {3, \
-15}, {4, -13}, {5, -12}, {5, -14}, {3, -16}, {6, -20}, {5, -16}, {3, \
-12}, {0, -13}, {3, -8}, {2, -7}, {1, -9}, {2, -9}, {2, -7}, {2, -4}, \
{4, -5}, {3, -7}, {4, -12}, {4, -15}, {1, -17}, {-2, -21}, {-4, -24}, \
{-3, -21}, {0, -26}, {1, -22}, {1, -20}, {-2, -15}, {0, -17}, {2, \
-12}, {3, -8}, {6, -13}, {6, -18}, {5, -23}, {5, -22}, {5, -21}, {8, \
-24}, {11, -27}, {13, -22}, {13, -17}, {15, -16}, {12, -14}, {10, \
-18}, {8, -14}, {5, -19}, {3, -21}, {0, -26}, {2, -30}, {3, -29}, {2, \
-33}, {-1, -37}, {2, -33}, {4, -38}, {4, -39}, {4, -42}, {1, -40}, \
{-1, -44}, {0, -48}, {0, -43}, {-1, -41}, {-4, -39}, {-6, -38}, {-3, \
-38}, {-1, -41}, {-1, -36}, {0, -33}, {1, -37}, {0, -42}, {-3, -39}, \
{-5, -36}, {-3, -31}, {-2, -27}, {-1, -22}, {-4, -18}, {-2, -20}}`
*)

```
Graphics[Line@randomWalk]
```

[image]

Comment: I'd use `Accumulate`, not `NestList`.

Comment: @2012rcampion How would you code that?

Comment: `Accumulate[RandomVariate[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{{-a, +a}, {-b, +b}}], n]]`

Comment: @2012rcampion  Doesn't include $(0,0)$ as requested, but that's easily fixed.

Comment: `Accumulate[_]~Prepend~{0,0}`.  Of course none of these solutions use `Module` as requested

Comment: Just realized that that's actually already kguler's answer... oops.