# Using Random walk on a region

Tags: plotting, random, scoping, simulation, procedural-programming

I want to simulate a random walk on two dimension equation using module. Checked the input so the path works

```
Walk[r_] := Module[{position, x, y, path},
position = {0, 0};
x = position[[1]];
y = position[[2]];
path = {position};
While[-r <= x <= r && -r <= y <= r,
x = x + RandomReal[{-1, 1}];
y = y + RandomReal[{-1, 1}];
position = {x, y};
AppendTo[path, position]
];
region = 
RegionPlot[-r <= s <= r && -r <= t <= r, {s, -r, r}, {t, -r, r}];
Show[region, ListPlot[path, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red]]
]
```

Used Walk[] as a tester and it seems fine,

```
Walk[100]
```

but when I tried to use a given equation of the region, it does not display the region nor the path.

```
Walk[x^2 + y^2 <= 50 || -10 <= x <= 10 && 4 <= y <= 10, x, y, 1, 11]
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57561)?

Comment: Briefly, but the user wanted to simulate a path through a shape such as a circle or square, but I'm trying to simulate through an equation (that gives the region) such as the one I put above.

Comment: There's at least an issue with your `r`: 
in `While[-r <= x <= r && -r <= y <= r`, `r` should be values, but instead you use `x^2 + y^2 <= 50 || -10 <= x <= 10 && 4 <= y <= 10`, which does not make sense.

Comment: The answers in the link given by J.M. rely on a region, but you could easily convert your inequalities to a region (see `ImplicitRegion` for instance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a comment on what is wrong with the code than an answer; the links in the comments point to-pretty much-authoritative implementations.

Looking at how `Walk` is implemented, it makes sense to evaluate something like `Walk[100]`-even though there are some minor tweaks in the code that will be proposed later in this note-but evaluating `Walk[x^2 + y^2 <= 50 || -10 <= x <= 10 && 4 <= y <= 10, x, y, 1, 11]` stops making sense from the first argument.

With the already provided implementation of `Walk`, argument 1 is expected to be a number whereas in the later evaluation it is an expression involving inequalities. Also, the initial implementation does not account for other arguments. Taking a guess, `x,y` are presumably the relevant variables in the expression involving inequalities; the rest of the input ie `1,11` is not to easy to understand. Without any explicit explanation, it is a matter or interpretation.

In what follows I will present a version of `Walk` that can accommodate inequalities:

```
(* requires a seed for reproducibility of random output *)
walk[r_, vars_?ListQ, seed_: 123456789] := Module[{reg, path, rands, rng},

  (* obtain the region *)
  reg = Reduce[r, vars, Reals];

  (* make reproducible *)
  BlockRandom[

   (* random steps in the unit ball *)
   rands := RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2];

   path = NestWhileList[
    (* produce the *next* random point... *)
    # + rands &,
    (* begin from the origin... *)
    {0., 0.},
    (* while the *current* point is within the region... *)
    reg /. Thread[vars -> #] &

   ], RandomSeeding -> seed];

  (* correct for the last point outside the region *)
  path = Most@path;

  (* range for RegionPlot *)
  rng = Sequence @@ MapIndexed[
     {vars[[#2[[-1]]]], Sequence @@ #1} &,
     Through[{Min, Max}[#]] & /@ Transpose[path]
     ];

  (* output *)
  Show[
   {
    RegionPlot[reg, Evaluate@rng],

    ListPlot[path,
     PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Small]}
     ]
    },

   PlotLabel -> Row[{"seed=", , seed}],

   Epilog -> {
     (* light blue point designates the starting point *)
     {Lighter@Blue, PointSize[Large], Point[First@path]},
     {Red, Opacity[0.4], Line[path]}
     }

   ]

  ]
```

Evaluating

```
BlockRandom[
   walk[x^2 + y^2 <= 50 || -10 <= x <= 10 && 4 <= y <= 10, {x, y}, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{10^3, 10^7}, 5],
   RandomSeeding -> 321456987
 ] // Partition[#, 3, 3, {1, 1}, {}] & // Grid
```

produces

> [image: Blockquote]

Following is the update of the original version of `Walk`:

```
(* again, use a seed for reproducibility *)
walk[r_, seed_: 123456789] := Module[{path},
  (* make reproducible *)
  BlockRandom[

   path = Most@NestWhile[
      (* produce next step *)
      # + RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2]} &,
      (* start from the origin *)
      {0., 0.},
      (* check if current step is valid *)
      And @@ Thread[-r < #[[-1]] < r] &
      ], RandomSeeding -> seed
   ];

  (* assemble output *)
  Show[
   {
    RegionPlot[True, {s, -r, r}, {t, -r, r}],
    ListPlot[path, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Small]}]
    },
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"seed=", , seed}],
   Epilog -> {
     (* use a blue point to depict the origin *)
     {Lighter@Blue, PointSize[Large], Point[First@path]},
     {Red, Opacity[0.4], Line[path]}
     }
   ]
  ]
```

Evaluating

```
BlockRandom[
   walk[10, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{10^3, 10^7}, 5],
   RandomSeeding -> 456789123
   ] // Partition[#, 3, 3, {1, 1}, {}] & // Grid
```

produces

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: I think the 1 and 11 suppose to be was x and y equals to. Apparently the image is suppose to look something like this https://imgur.com/a/Ra23i

Comment: the linked image can be reproduced if you change in the first implementation of `walk` the range in `RegionPlot` appropriately, get rid of the line using `Most`, use `RandomInteger` instead of `RandomReal`, use `Length` on `path` to count the number of steps traversed and modify the `Epilog` in `Show` in a way to represent the highlighted points present in the linked image. Inputs `1` and `11` cannot correspond to the starting point of the walk. Having said that, it feels really awkward doing someone else's homework;please don't post your homework problems as questions