# How do you create a 2D random walk?

Tags: random

I've been trying to create a 2D random walk process for my project.
The question is as follows,
Create a 2-dimensional random walk process where the walker can move
up, down, left, or right. The walker should have an equal chance of
going in any direction (25%). Create a graph of a single walk.

We've been using these functions but I'm unsure how to go about it correctly.

```
`A = Table[0, {1}, {2}];
Do[
 x = RandomReal[];
 Which[
  x < 0.25, A[[i + 1, 1]] = A[[i, 1]] + 1;
  x < 0.25, A[[i + 1, 2]] = A[[i, 2]] - 1],
 {i, 1, 0}, {i, 1, 1}]
ListLinePlot[A]`
```

It's supposed to look like this.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could draw inspiration from previously asked questions on this site (use the search bar at the top of the page). For instance, this question and its answers might be a good start: [2D random walk within a bounded area](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57561/27951).

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For unbounded area, the following should work

```
ListLinePlot[Accumulate@RandomChoice[{{1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}}, 500]]
```

Comment: Yes, that's it.